# Lighttpd URL rewrite with negative matching

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm trying to rewrite urls that have an image in them but not 'php', for example:

I want to match this:

```
http://domain.com/trees.jpg
```

and rewrite it to this:

```
http://domain.com/viewimg.php?image=trees.jpg
```

But not match this:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?image=trees.jpg
```

because it has 'php' in it, so it shouldn't do any rewriting at all to that url.

I'm no good with regex but I've been trying a number of variations and none have worked.
Here's an example of one variation I've tried:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"(?!php\b)\b\w+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$" => "/viewimg.php?image=$1.$2"
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.  It will fail matches where there is the string `\.php` anywhere behind `\w+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)`

Pattern: `(?<!.*\.php.*)\b(\w+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))$`

Replace: `viewing.php?image=$1`

Tested:

```
http://domain.com/trees.jpg  --->  http://domain.com/viewing.php?image=trees.jpg
http://domain.com/index.php/trees.jpg  ---> http://domain.com/index.php/trees.jpg
http://domain.com/index.php/image=trees.jpg  ---> http://domain.com/index.php/image=trees.jpg
```

**Edit:**

Above uses non-constant-length lookbehind, which is apparently [not supported on many platforms](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Without this I don't know if you can codify "match XYZ when ABC is nowhere in the string behind it" in pure regex.  Maybe someone with more regex-fu than me knows a way.

As a somewhat less general solution, this will check only if the fixed string `.php?image=` does not come right before the image name:

Pattern: `(?<!\.php\?image=)\b(\w+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))$`

Replace: `viewing.php?image=$1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't rewrite http://domain.com/trees.jpg, I just get a 404.

Comment: I tested it in .NET regex, maybe your env does not have the same feature set.  Are you saying the match fails completely against `domain.com/trees.jpg` ?

Comment: Yes, I also tested it at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it doesn't match any part of domain.com/trees.jpg.

Comment: I see.  I am using a variable-sized lookbehind, which is apparently only supported in .NET and JGsoft. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html  Let me see if I can change it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that works great. However the 'image' string before '=' isn't always the same so I changed it to this and it works like a charm: (?<!=)\b(\w+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))$ Thanks again for your help!